# How are the saved game data and user profile data files related?

Tags: borderlands-2, ps3

Must you save and restore the two files simultaneously?  Or can I restore a saved game file without restoring the user profile?  What information is in the user profile?

Comment: Not sure about Borderlands 2 as i have been waiting for the GotY edition but in Borderlands 1 the user profile had the character level, stats and equipment, the game save was like which quests had been done, which areas had been opened up etc, this way on local split screen 2 vastly different characters could play in the same game (ie. level 5 solider with basic gear with a level 40 Siren with endgame gear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally restore only the character save. The user profile contains the general values for the profile (such as badass tokens or number of golden keys).

You can either

- import another profile file with a different amount of badass tokens and golden keys and all your character will get them too
- import another save on your profile and the character will have the amount of goldens keys and badass tokens available on your profile

Answer (score 0):

The User Profile Data contains the Badass Rank, Badass Tokens, Heads, Skins, and Golden Keys.

Answer (score 0):

The user profile contains the Badass Rank, Badass Tokens, Head/skins and golden keys. changing the amount of golden keys (E.G by a shift code) gives them to you for all of your characters to share. editing the badass rank(E.G by completing challenges) gives you a higher badass rank for all of your characters and gives you badass tokens when you get a high enough badass rank, it is harder to get badass tokens as your badass rank goes up, but tokens are very easy to get when the badass rank is lower